# Sharepoint 2010 timer job is not executed

Tags: sharepoint-2010, installation, solution, timer-jobs

Lately, when I run a command of upgrading or uninstalling a .wsp, a job is created and scheduled to run in the same minute instead of executing the actual command. If I try to start the job manually it does not start, simply reschedules itself for the current timestamp.

I think some global service which is supposed to run all the jobs is not working...

Do you have any idea what might cause this, or how could I fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the SharePoint Timer service(sptimerv4) was not started. When I tried to start it manually, I received an error saying "The service did not start due to a logon failure". I reconfigured the account used to run this service (even if it appeared to be correctly configured), and... voila!

This link helped me to fix it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182790.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if the SharePoint Timer service (sptimerv4) was started or not. Next check if the service account has expired. If it has expired, add service account credentials for Timer service and schedule it again.